# Using file opened by GUI in python?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, gui, tkinter

I have these lines of code:

```
import tkFileDialog, arcpy, arcpy.da, numpy as np, Tkinter
import arcpy.mapping as mapping

fc = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('shapefiles','*.shp')],title='Choose a Shapefile')
print 'fc = {0}'.format(fc)
desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)

#Find the number of rows(alternatives) and print it!
number_of_rows = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
R = int(number_of_rows.getOutput(0))
print R
#Find the number of columns(criterias) and print it!
C = len(arcpy.ListFields(fc))
print C
```

It creates a GUI where i can browse and open a shapefile. This shapefile is an ArcMap shapefile with a layer and an attribute table. With this algorithm i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Th\Desktop\Python Scripting\Σμαραγδάς Αθανάσιος     Διπλωματική\Python Codes\Python_Codes\Script1.py", line 8, in <module>
    number_of_rows = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 13613, in GetCount
raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000229: Cannot open C:/Users/Th/Desktop/waterways.shp
Failed to execute (GetCount).
```

How can i solve this? I can access the file with the line below and do the same work with it, but i want to create a GUI so that i can open any file i want to by browsing.

```
fc = "C:/Users/Th/Desktop/waterways.shp"
```

I am trying to open the file with the GUI and then use it for any reason i want.But after it prints the directory of the file(as the algorithm demands), i get the error above.

Comment: Does it work when you manually add it?

Comment: Yes it does work perfectly. @JamesLeversha

Comment: I have worked with tkFileDialog and did not have a problem. What does the print 'fc = {0}'.format(fc) output?

Comment: Also do a print desc after `desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)` to see if a describe object is getting created. Maybe try and set the workspace variable in the code, `arcpy.env.workspace = fc = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('shapefiles','*.shp')],title='Choose a Shapefile')`

Comment: fc = {0}'.format(fc) prints the path of fc: fc = C:/Users/Th/Desktop/waterways.shp @BenSNadler

Comment: @JamesLeversha i did set the workspace variable in the code before but the problem still occurs... File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 13613, in GetCount  raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 000229: Cannot open C:/Users/VOCALIST/Desktop/waterways.shp
Failed to execute (GetCount). This is the exact error if it helps more...

Comment: even if in the same code i add: with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor...i get an error: TypeError: 'field_names' must be string or non empty sequence of strings

Comment: only other thing i can think of is specifying root for tk.`root = Tkinter.Tk()
fc = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('shapefiles','*shp')],title='Choose a Shapefile')
root.destroy()`

Comment: `I have always just used this def and it has always worked ok. 
# def for getting file names from the user
def get_filename_from_user(message):
  root = Tk()
  root.withdraw()
  filenames = askopenfilenames(title='blah')
  filenames = root.tk.splitlist(filenames)
  return filenames`

Comment: Btw in the search cursor you need to define the fields. try, with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, '*') as cursor

Comment: @JamesLeversha fields are defined above but i didnt show you but thank you anyway!

Comment: From the back and forth in comments I am not clear what the precise code snippet is that you are asking about, along with the full error as text, and any other output.  Would you be able to [edit] your question to make sure that it reads clearly, please?

Comment: Might be an Esri bug? See this on Error 000229, about background processing being enabled: [http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012177](http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012177). Your code works just fine for me in a Python console using one of my own shapefiles.

Comment: @PauloRaposo I think your comment would be suitable to post as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @PauloRaposo:

> [This m]ight be an Esri bug ... See this on Error 000229, about
>   background processing being enabled:
>   http://support.esri.com/technical-article/000012177.
>   Your code works just fine for me in a Python console using one of my
>   own shapefiles.